# Kill linux command in ruby if timed-out

Tags: ruby

I need a solution how I can kill a system call in ruby and proceed, when this call takes too much time. If timed-out I want to set a mock. Timeout method in ruby doesn't help because it raises an error instead of moving to the end of the code.

```
    Timeout::timeout(5) {
      a = `sleep 30; echo 1`
    }

puts a
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your code and any error's you encounter?  see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That's how Timeout works. You'll need to `rescue` the timeout exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this illustrates it but for example 2 ruby files:

```
#slow_proceess.rb
puts 'starting.... waiting...'

10.times do
    puts "slow process runing..."
    sleep 1
end

puts 'done exiting'

#fast.rb
pid = Process.spawn('ruby slow_process.rb')
# after x seconds we can kill the process with
`kill -9 #{pid}`
```

Or in your example use instance variable to access it outside of the block and also rescue error (thanks @tadman):

```
begin
    Timeout::timeout(5) {
      @pid = Process.spawn('sleep 30; echo 1')
    }
rescue Timeout::Error
    puts "#{@pid} process has timed out"
end

# do stuff
```